# VBA Transpose Loop and Start a new line when criteria met

Tags: vba, excel

My data is separated by column and each day is separated by a blank row in that column. Basically I need a VBA Macro to make this data:

```
1995 (1)
(23:00)

Math 0630
0830 Break 0930
1000 English 1200
1200 Lunch 1300

1995 (2)
(12:45)

Chemistry 0630
0830 Lab 0930
1000 Bio 1200
1200 Lunch 1300
```

appear like this in a new sheet:

```
1995 (1)    (23:00) Math 0630   0830 Break 0930 1000 English 1200   1200 Lunch 1300 
1995 (2)    (12:45) Chemistry 0630  0830 Lab 0930   1000 Bio 1200   1200 Lunch 1300
```

I also need the vba code to separate each line when a new day starts. Can someone help?

This is what I have so far..

```
    Sub blnkrows()
Do
    p = p + 20
    If Rows(p).Find("*") Is Nothing Then Exit Do
Loop
    y = Range(Rows(1), Rows(p))
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
    Range(.Rows(1), .Rows(p)) = y
    End With
End Sub
```

But that only copies the data to a new sheet.

Comment: Is the list always in the same pattern 2 rows of data, 1 row blank, 4 rows of data,1 row blank? Or will it change?

Comment: It will change. There is always blank row(s) when a new day starts. Sometimes there are 5 rows of data sometimes 10. It all depends It always starts the same though. 2 rows of data 1 blank but then it varies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you are asking

Edit this code is based on private conversations with OP.  There were idiosyncrasies to the patterns that required more review.

```
Sub blnkrows()
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim p As Integer, i&
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim t As Integer
Dim c As Long
Dim u As Long



Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set tws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
i = 1
With ws
Do Until i > 100000
    u = 0
    For c = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ReDim arr(0) As Variant
        p = 0
        t = 0
            Do Until .Cells(i + p, c) = "" And t = 1
                If .Cells(i + p, c) = "" Then
                    t = 1

                Else
                    arr(UBound(arr)) = .Cells(i + p, c)
                    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
                End If
                p = p + 1
            Loop

        If p > u Then
            u = p

        End If
        If c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Then
            If .Cells(i + p, c).End(xlDown).Row > 100000 And .Cells(i + p, 1).End(xlDown).Row < 100000 Then
                i = .Cells(i + u, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            Else
                i = .Cells(i + p, c).End(xlDown).Row
            End If

        End If
        tws.Cells(tws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr

    Next c

Loop
End With
With tws
    .Rows(1).Delete
    For i = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Left(.Cells(i, 1), 4) <> Left(.Cells(i - 1, 1), 4) Then
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "Subscript out of range" What would be the reason for that? Also it is leaving out the 4th row of data and also only loops for the two columns. After that, it doesn't spit out the correct data

Comment: @Ben What line throws the error, my guess is `Set tws = Worksheets("Sheet2")`. if this is so, it means that you do not have a "sheet2" either rename it in the code to the sheet you want or add a "Sheet2"

Comment: Yup. I figured that out. Another question/issue It is doing it correctly for the first column but I have 6 columns of data. Is there a simple addition that can make this command for all 6 columns.

Comment: @Ben I missed that part in the Original Question.  I have updated the code.

Comment: the updated code actually made things worse. It cuts off my data half way through and is putting data is wrong positions.

Comment: @Ben I made a last change to ensure that it does not cut off the data.  see the line `tws.Cells(tws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, ubound(arr)+1) = arr`.  Try that and let me know.  If that does not work send me a copy of the data at scott.craner@gmail.com and I will help.